# AngularJS - UI-Grid CellTemplate Button appearing twice on scroll

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

Using UI-Grid's cellTemplate in options like this:

```
field: 'isHflrReplaceable', displayName: 'Lead Replacement', width: 200, enableSorting: false, cellTemplate: hflrTemplate
```

Template looks like this:

```
var hflrTemplate = '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents">'
                        + '<span class="hflr" ng-show="(row.entity.creditStatus == \'Credit Accepted\') || (row.entity.creditStatus == \'Credit Rejected\')">{{row.entity.creditStatus}}</span>' //IF status = Credit accepted or Rejected
                        + '<span class="hflr" ng-show="(row.entity.creditStatus == \'Credit Pending\') && (row.entity.isHflrReplaceable == 1)"><button ng-if="row.entity.isHflrReplaceable == 1" ng-click="grid.appScope.setSelected(row.entity);" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#HFLRModal"><span class="fa fa-reply m-r-xs"></span>View/Edit</button></span>' //IF status = Credit Pending && can return
                        + '<span class="hflr" ng-show="(row.entity.creditStatus == null) && (row.entity.isHflrReplaceable == 1)"><button ng-if="row.entity.isHflrReplaceable == 1" ng-click="grid.appScope.setSelected(row.entity);" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#HFLRModal"><span class="fa fa-reply m-r-xs"></span>Request Replacement</button></span>' //IF status = null && can return
                        + '</div>';
```

Correct items show up as expected. The list is a little long... ~200 or so rows.

When I scroll up some length past the view port and then back up, the template spans that just contain the text are fine. However, the template spans that show the buttons have an additional copy of the same button. In fact, the buttons keep adding to it as I scroll further away from the button and then back to the buttons. I checked the DOM and every time I scroll back to the button, there is an additional button. What the heck is going on?

Note: I'm not manipulating any data, I'm just scrolling the table view with the scroll bar.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. False alarm.

Looks like someone added `ng-if` in the button itself. I dont know why. And removing that from the button tag itself, fixed the problem.